# admob ad doesn't appear and there is no error

Tags: android, admob

I created a simple app with admob ad but the ad doesn't appear and there is no error, the API level is 21.

here is my code:

xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="76dp"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2615894909216466/7973602032">
     </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

java file:

```
 AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
 AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
 adView.loadAd(request);
```

the logcat message:

```
10-31 16:30:11.267: W/ScreenOrientationListener(1199): Removing an       inexistent observer!
10-31 16:30:11.383: W/Ads(1199): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
10-31 16:30:11.506: W/art(1199): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
10-31 16:30:11.547: W/AwContents(1199): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
10-31 16:30:11.647: W/art(1199): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
10-31 16:30:11.730: W/Ads(1199): Failed to load ad: 0
```

Comment: Sometime the ad doesn't load from server and always the reason appears in logcat, be attention and track it then add it to the post.

Comment: @I added the logcat in the post

Comment: If you test the app in emulator, try to test it on real device.

Comment: @Mohamed I tried it in my device but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

1. You have Internet permission in your manifest file
   name="banner_ad_unit_id">yourAppID
2. You have this line in your Java class: MobileAds.initialize(mainActivity.getApplicationContext(), "YourAppID");